# Get Website ID from Website Name

Tags: collection, magento-1, websites

As the title says. I don't want the ID of the current website, I want the ID of any website by supplying only that websites name.

I have this code:

```
$siteModel = Mage::getResourceModel( 'core/website_collection' )->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site )->getFirstItem();
$siteId = $siteModel->getId();
```

But `$siteId` ends up empty.

If all i have the name of a website, then how can i get its ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need debug the collection by `->getSelect()->__toString()`

for checking it give right value or not.

```
    $siteModelCollection = Mage::getResourceModel( 'core/website_collection' )->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site );
// print the Query
    echo $Query = $siteModelCollection ->getSelect()->__toString();
    echo $siteId =$siteModelCollection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

### Update:

**Use load():**

for this case you need to  call `load()` function of `resource model` of `core/website` for getting proper collection

Now you can get id of first store by using below code:

```
$siteModelCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->addFieldToFilter( 'name', $site)->load();
echo $Query = $siteModelCollection ->getSelect()->__toString();
echo $siteId =$siteModelCollection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

Comment: The first echo returns `SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_website` AS `main_table` WHERE (name = 'base')` - this seems ok to me? Does it seem ok to you? The second echo returns an empty string.

Comment: adding `->load()` worked perfectly! thank you very much!

Comment: load() should be after filter

Comment: ya. right[................

Answer (score 3):

Websites are already loaded on startup, so there is no need for additional queries. You can and should use:

```
$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
```

to receive them. Then to look up by **name**:

```
foreach ($websites as $id => $website) {
    if ($website->getName() === $name) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get website ID from its code:

```php
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite($code)->getId();
```